# Compare original to modified images

Tags: python, image-processing, feature-extraction

I am working on a project in which I want to compare a non-modified original picture against a dataset that contains images of which some are small to medium alterations of the original image. These alterations can go from simple color changes, gradients, lighting, flipping/rotating the image to even modifications done by a professional in Photoshop and used for a movie poster.

My goal is to identify, with rather good accuracy, if the original image has been used in one of the images.

I have already tried many different approaches:

- Perceptual Hashing
- Feature Extraction
- Both with and without Machine Learning techniques
- Tensorflow
- ...

However, I always have the feeling like all the above have some shortcomings in terms of accuracy and performance.

Therefore I was wondering if someone knows a good Python project (Github, website,...) that will allow me to achieve my goal.

Comment: What exactly did you try? I think a deep learning approach should yield the desired result.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe a specific problem you have with one of your approaches and what has been done so far to solve it. Maybe we can help you with that.